# To open an external link in new window instead of same tab in SharePoint 2013 site

Tags: sharepoint-2013

There is an external link in our SharePoint 2013 site, on clicking it, we'll be re-directed to an external site. Currently, this site is opening in the same tab, we instead want it to open in new window.

URL: https://abc.example.com/ido/startSSO.ping?PartnerSpId=https://admin-sso.sample.com&ACRIdx=1&TARGET=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sample.com%2Fplo%2Fsample%2Fsrch.list%3Fx_mod_id%3D1%26x_action%3Dsearch

Note: The original URL is not provided due to security reasons.

Do I need to modify anything to make it open in new window?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by giving target="_blank" in anchor tag.